# SharePoint 2010 books to prepare - dev focus

Tags: 2010, books

SharePoint 2010 is going to bring a lot of new technologies to SharePoint developers such as Linq and Silverlight that we may not have touched before. What are your recommended dev books to read to get up to speed on what SP2010 has to offer?

Answer (score 5):

These will be must have technologies (regardless of SharePoint 2010)

- LINQ - [Pro Linq in C#](http://www.apress.com/book/view/1590597893) (Apress)
- Silverlight - [Pro Silverlight 2.0] (Apress)
- Silverlight - Read about MVVM pattern
- jQuery - jQuery in Action

Plus every dev should really learn about IIS 7.0 and Windows 2008 Server.

(additional links not added as only allowed one per post :S)

Answer (score 3):

One book for developers to read before the 2010 hits the streets should be: [Linq in Action](http://linqinaction.net/)

/WW

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this site http://sharepointbooks.web.officelive.com 
It contains links to books and reviews on SharePoint 2010.

Comment: This link is broken.

Answer (score 2):

It behooves a SharePoint Developer to learn and effectively use PowerShell. A few of the books suggested are -

- [Automating SharePoint 2010 with Windows PowerShell 2.0](http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0470939206.html)
- [PowerShell for Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Administrators](http://www.mhprofessional.com/product.php?isbn=0071747974)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to print material, I would consider a [PluralSight](http://www.pluralsight-training.net) subscription as well. It's not books but all of their videos are amazingly well done. They have material specifically about SharePoint as well as Linq, Work Flow, and Silverlight.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another collection of SharePoint 2010 Books:

http://wssv4faq.mindsharp.com/Lists/v4FAQ/V%20Books.aspx

Please note that, not all titles are released as of today.  Most of these are for Future Releases.